# Compare values with in a table in SQl

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is MyTable structure

```
MyTable : ID, Date 

Select ID, Date from MyTable

ID     Date

50    2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 
51    2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 
52    2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

I need to get the result like this.

```
ID     Date

50    2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
50    2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
50    2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 

51    2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 
51    2013-01-03 00:00:00.000

52    2013-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

How do i get the results ?

Comment: Why is `50` with 3 dates and `51` with 2 and `52` with one? Where the that last date come from?

Comment: I need to add  extra rows with the ID and the upcoming dates.

Comment: My question was not about _what_ you need to add, but what logic determines it. It makes no sense without more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want to get a list of dates. Of so, then you can use a recursive CTE to get the list of dates:

```
;with data(id, date) as
(
  select id, date
  from mytable
  union all
  select id, dateadd(day, 1, date)
  from data
  where dateadd(day, 1, date) <= '1/3/2013'
)
select *
from data
order by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5177d/2).  This will generate the list of dates for each ID between the current date in your table and the end date that you provide.  In my example it is `1/3/2013`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work a bit faster ONLY if there is a CLUSTERED INDEX on the ID column, else bluefeet's solution is fantastic!

```
SELECT T1.ID
        ,Date = DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))+1, '2013-01-03')
FROM MyTable T1
JOIN MyTable T2 ON T1.ID <= T2.ID
```